# Swift 2.0: Type of expression is ambigous without more context

Tags: swift

Tried understanding the other issues similar to this, but couldn't figure it out. `Type of expression is ambigous without more context` shows on 'CalendarUnitHour' in this line of code:

```
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: date)
```